# create array of POSTs from string array

Tags: php, post

Let's say I have an array of strings:

```
$arr = array('prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3');
```

and I want to use this array to create `bind_param` for sql request. Each string of the array however should be inside `$_POST[]`. So this should be the result:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['prop1'], $_POST['prop2'], $_POST['prop3']);
```

Is something like that possible (PHP 7.x)?

Comment: No, that is not directly possible. But you can create your own array that contains the three elements under those three keys first, and then use the spread operator in your bind_param call.

Comment: @CBroe the array is used in another places like MySQL UPDATE SET values and then in form fields. So it can't be made by $_POSTs

Comment: Once you get the keys you need from `$_POST` you can just unpack the array in `bind_param` using `...` (splat operator)

Comment: _"So it can't be made by $_POSTs"_ - I don't get what you are trying to say there. You said you _wanted_ to use `$_POST['prop1']` in your bind_param statement, so where else is that value supposed to come from, if not $_POST?

Comment: @CBroe I meant that `$arr` is used also in other places, not just in the `bind_param` where I need those `$_POST['prop1']...`, so I can't make it directly with POSTs (`array('$_POST['prop1'], ...`). I thought you mean something like this: `array('prop1' => $_POST['prop1']`.

Comment: @Dharman I don't get it. I don't need keys from POST. I just need to create array of POSTs. Also the suggested answer seems to be away from what I need.

Comment: Why not? Have you tried it? It matches your problem description exactly.

Comment: I meant create a _new_ array here specifically for this. For each parameter name you have in `$arr`, you add the corresponding $_POST element to your new array. And then you use that new array in your bind_param call, with the spread operator.

Comment: @Dharman because I don't have 2 arrays to use array_intersect_key(), don't have key/value pairs and don't getting keys from $_POST, sorry. So, I don't understand why this question was closed and I think comment from CBroe should be the answer.

Comment: You have two arrays: `$arr` and `$_POST`. Comment from CBroe says the same thing

Comment: @Dharman oh, I did not think about $_POSTs as an array. Regarding the suggested answer, that is kind of advanced form me to come up with that approach. Thanks.